# Alternativas para servidor e deploy de aplicações Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, deploy

Sempre que faço alguma aplicação Rails configuro meu servidor com Nginx e Passenger, e geralmente faço *deploy* via GIT ou rsync.

Sei que existem outras formas de fazer o *deploy* e também de configuração do servidor. Existe alguma forma mais simples e/ou mais performática para aplicação comparada com Nginx e Passenger?

Comment: Se você quer dizer outros servidores que suportem Rails, você também pode usar o **Apache + Passenger**. Havia o Mongrel, mas esse foi descontinuado. Agora se você quer dizer a respeito de como fazer o deploy aí têm o **[Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/rails)**. Já conhece? Existe um artigo [aqui](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/22977/ruby-on-rails/deploy-de-aplicacoes-rails-com-capistrano/) e outro [aqui](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html).

Comment: Olá Ricardo Obrigado pela resposta, eu antes usava Apache + Passenger... Mudei para Nginx por questões de performance mesmo... Sobre o Capistrano realmente ainda não usei. Vou dar uma lida obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

No caso do Nginx, é a melhor opção.

Já sobre o passenger, recomendo a leitura:

https://www.engineyard.com/articles/rails-server

Meus 2c: Eu uso passenger, dificilmente trocaria a comodidade pelos ms de performance a mais que os outros prometem.

Answer (score 0):

Seu Jota, para deploy, eu ultilizo o Mina. É uma ferramenta para deploy automatizado bem interessante e bem fácil de usar, da uma olhada:

https://github.com/nadarei/mina